# AWS LAMP Stack connection to MySQL Database using PHP Issues

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, amazon-web-services

I have been at this for days trying to get this to work. I just followed the AWS tutorial and installed a LAMP stack on an EC2 instance of AMAZON LINUX. I have been trying to just do basic connections to it. Just easy Insert statements and I continually get this error:

The server is working.. i have a test file that works.

My database is set up and ready. It will receive an id, a username, a password, and an email address. But I cannot connect to mysql. 
I have: 
1) set up a user and granted all privelages
2) checked the my.cnf file. There is no "bind-address" listed to change, but I added one in just to check. I added my server IP. Still did not work. 
3) Security groups are wide open. I have SSH, HTTP, HTTPS, and MySQL accepting inbound connects from "Anywhere".

Here is the simple task I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<?php

$servername = "xx.xx.xxx.xx;
$username = "ec2-user";
$password = "112233445566";
$dbname = "db";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (id, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES(1, Fake, User, fake3mail@gmail.com);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Task I'm trying to accomplish: connect to MySQL database and insert a row of data.

Actual result: Error and the inability to connect.

I have scoured the internet for DAYS now trying to get this to work. What the heck am I missing here?! Are there even more configurations that must be done? I have tried every single thing that I've read and it does not work .

Comment: I believe you have entire LAMP stack on same EC2 instance. Have you tried using **localhost** as the servername.

Comment: I have just changed it to localhost and I have the same issue. the name of that file is table.php. Am i correct in assuming that the way to connect to is is by going to the public DNS address with the file name after it just like all other files?  For instance:  ec2-54-174-71-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com/table.php

Answer (score 0):

When I go to this page, it is working so I will assume that you fixed that issue: ec2-54-174-71-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

For your database, change the `$servername` to `"localhost"`. There is no need to do a DNS lookup to resolve your own system.

If you are having problems with your PHP code (you do from the last comment), look at your PHP.INI file. In this file will be the location for your error logs. Look for the line `"error_log = "` This file will store the errors for your PHP programs (scripts). Just look at the bottom of the file for the latest error messages. If error_log is not configured, then configure it.

One problem that I do see with your code is that you are not put single quotes around your strings. Your values should look like this: `VALUES(1, 'Fake;', 'User', 'fake3mail@gmail.com')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have fixed the single quote issue. I have also found the error log. It states this:  7] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Table' (T_STRING) in /var/www/htm                                      l/table.php on line 18

Comment: Probably because your $sql line does not have an ending quote to close the string.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what's going on. apparently you cannot grant permission to ec2-user (the default user) as I was doing. I created a new separate user and granted all permissions to that user and it works fine now.